# rosjava gradle compilation loop

Tags: ros, rosjava, gradle

[image: Rosanswers logo]

trying to compile rosjava using gradle following:

http://docs.rosjava.googlecode.com/hg/rosjava_core/html/building.html

i managed to get to fourth step, when i run: ./gradlew rosjava:install
everything seems to compile good, but once i hit

```
Building > :rosjava:test > 19 tests completed
```

it seems to freeze, i ran it with ./gradlew rosjava:isntall --debug and it seems
to loop this forever:

```
23:15:47.667 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.WorkerProtocol] Dispatching request to worker: [Request consumer: 702b4444-12e7-4914-be76-28b05bff8732, payload: [MethodInvocation method: output()]]
23:15:47.667 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.WorkerProtocol] Dispatching request to worker: [Request consumer: 702b4444-12e7-4914-be76-28b05bff8732, payload: [MethodInvocation method: output()]]
> Building > :rosjava:test > 19 tests completed
```

using:

```
------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 1.0-milestone-9
------------------------------------------------------------

Gradle build time: Tuesday, March 13, 2012 4:10:09 PM UTC
Groovy: 1.8.6
Ant: Apache Ant(TM) version 1.8.2 compiled on December 20 2010
Ivy: 2.2.0
JVM: 1.6.0_23 (Sun Microsystems Inc. 20.0-b11)
OS: Linux 3.0.0-16-generic-pae i386

Apache Maven 3.0.4 (r1232337; 2012-01-17 10:44:56+0200)
Maven home: /home/vaida/programs/apache-maven-3.0.4
Java version: 1.6.0_23, vendor: Sun Microsystems Inc.
Java home: /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "linux", version: "3.0.0-16-generic-pae", arch: "i386", family: "unix"
```

Ubuntu 11.10

Anyone know what might be causing that loop or how to turn off that test?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/30083/rosjava-gradle-compilation-loop/) by [kurmis](https://answers.ros.org/users/1980/kurmis/) on ROS Answers with karma: 51 on 2012-03-20

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [kurmis](https://answers.ros.org/users/1980/kurmis/) on 2012-03-25**:
managed to compile it with: ./gradlew rosjava:install -x tests

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As you said in your comment, a workaround is to use ./gradlew rosjava:install -x tests.

However, please file an issue and specify which test is failing to complete. You should be able to figure that out with ./gradle rosjava:test --info.

See http://code.google.com/p/rosjava/issues/list

---

Originally posted by [damonkohler](https://answers.ros.org/users/653/damonkohler/) with karma: 3838 on 2012-03-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1